# Swift CollectionView first cell add user button and other cell load from image array

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am trying to create a `UICollcetionView` with first cell add button for add user and from second cell I need to load Image array string into another cells. Here, I am using two separate `cell` but I am not getting first cell into my output. Please provide me solution or another best method.

I am trying to get below output

[image]

**Multiple Cell Code**

```
// MARK: CollectionView Delegate
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let firstCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addusercell", for: indexPath) as! AddParticipantsCollectionViewCell
        return firstCell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userscollectionview", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ParticipantsCollectionViewCell
        cell.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
if indexPath.item == 0  {
    // first cell
}
else {

   // second cell
   cell.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.item - 1]
}
```

---

Correct dataSource method ( **remove it** )

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1 // Section should set return 1 or default is optional 
}
```

And change `numberOfItemsInSection` to

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count + 1
}
```

Comment: if I add `indexPath.item == 0` from array may have a chance to skip first index right? is it a good method? I thought to expect first always static index and others load from array because` item 0` always need to be visible but other `items` only available based on `JSON` data.

Comment: subtract 1 from the `indexPath.item ` when you access the array and you'll get the first item inside the else of  `indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.item == 0 `

Comment: it is showing each cells 3 images, so totally 6 showing. Where I need to  subtract? Could you please update your code details.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two sections in the collectionView you also need to set the number of items in each individual section:

```
    // MARK: CollectionView Delegate
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
      return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      if section == 0 {
        return 1 // return 1 item in cell (+ cell)
      } else {
        return imageArray.count
      }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let firstCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addusercell", for: indexPath) as! AddParticipantsCollectionViewCell
            return firstCell
        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userscollectionview", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ParticipantsCollectionViewCell
            cell.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
```

I hope it's been of any help.